# Warning: variable is uninitialized

Tags: c++, variables, initialization

I have the following piece of code:

```
class circularList
{
public:
    circularList() : data(0), next(this) {}
public:
    int data;
    circularList* next;
};

int main()
{
    circularList* root = new circularList;
}
```

I keep getting a warning saying that variable `circularList* next` is uninitialized, but I can see if I run the code that is initialized with the address of the pointer `root`.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6346f3e1e3c05711). Please specify your compiler and the options used.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: @Ovidiu Firescu gcc HEAD 10.0.0 does not issue a warning.

Comment: [MSVC doesn't seem to reproduce it either](https://godbolt.org/z/mbJ6mp).

Comment: http://prntscr.com/p85izj

Comment: No warning from XCode either.

Comment: @OvidiuFirescu, share your compiler version as well please.

Comment: How can I check what compiler version is used?

Comment: I think the version of the Microsoft C/C++ compiler is 19.21

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pointer is clearly initialised in the example. This appears to be a compiler bug, as there should be no warning. You should report it to the maintainers.

Answer (score 3):

It's either bug or misfeature of static analyzer. It's intended behaviour is to react on code like this:

```
class circularList
{
public:
    circularList() : data2(0), data1(this->data2) {}
public:
    int data1;
    int data2;
};
```

`data2` actually initialized after `data1` (which produces another warning) and expression starting with `this`, `this->XXX`, prompts the check. In your case `->XXX` is not present and it confuses the analyzer. This should be a regression, because some builds of older compilers  (as old as VS2005 or VS2008), or some very ancient `gcc` or `lcc` (not stable builds) expressed similar concerns.

There is still a case when `this` should not be used - if there is a virtual inheritance, or if initialization tries to call a virtual function.

Answer (score -3):

`next(this)` should bad choice since `this` is logically not created when passed like this. Maybe use `next = this` instead in the constructor block.

PS: `gcc (GCC) 4.8.5` did not issue any warning.

```
class circularList
{
public:
    circularList() : data(0) { next = this; }
public:
    int data;
    circularList* next;
};

int main()
{
    circularList* root = new circularList;
    std::cout << root->data << "\n";
    std::cout << root->next->data << "\n";
    root->data = 1;
    std::cout << root->data << "\n";
    std::cout << root->next->data << "\n";
}
```

Comment: I want to make a circular list, and if I have a single element I want that element to point to itself

Comment: Corrected, and ensured this does not give warning.

Comment: `this` is valid in the constructor's member initializer list

Comment: yes, @Mat, `gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)`  did not issue a warning.

Comment: Still gives a warning and I don't understand why, because it looks initialized to me...

Comment: `this` is just a pointer, whether the object that `this` points to is already fully alive is irrelevant here

Comment: it's a bug\misconcept which present also in old gcc versions (before 4.7). Was the reason that our devs thought that it was an UB to try use `this` and `offsetof ` in initializer list. It's quite possible it is intended behavior of MS compiler due to implementation, even MS2010 gives warnings of 4th level at that.